Is there an example of factless fact table with degenerate dimensions?
I came across the problem when i did a homework on my class. Let's just say i have Doctor table, which stores information about doctors, Patient table, which stores information about patients that came to check their health and Record table stores, which stores information about the examination. The record table has reference to Doctor and Patient primary keys. The homework told me to design a fact table to count the number of patients a doctor has examnined throughout a day, a month or a year. I have 2 options, the first is to use additive fact table (i will store a column to count number of patients a doctor examined for a day from Record table) and i will have 2 dimension tables: Dim_Date and Dim_Patients. The second choice is to store Patient primary key, Doctor primary key and Record primary key (each row indicates a patient examined by a doctor) and no dimension tables are involed (as they're degenerate dimension), so that when i want to count number of patients, i just use Count(*) function. I want to ask that there's a possiblity for a second choice to happen in real life?
I did ask chatGPT and it told me there's a chance for a factless fact table with degenerate tables but i didn't completely trust it.

Why don’t you create an appointments fact table with a record per appointment?

Can i ask what are the dimensions and the measure of the fact table?

What do you think they might be? As this is a homework question you are expected to show additional effort to answer the question yourself

I do have answers but i wanted to know there's a factless fact table with degenerate dimensions in real life situation or no

Hi - the point I was making was that a factless fact table was not the correct solution to your problem. However, to answer your specific question, yes, a factless fact table can have degenerate dimensions - a fact table can have degenerate dimensions regardless of whether it is factless or not

Thank you very much, really appriciate your answer
